# chardet apparently wrong on Big5

Tags: python, unicode, big5, chardet

I'm decoding a large (about a gigabyte) flat file database, which mixes character encodings willy nilly.  The python module `chardet` is doing a good job, so far, of identifying the encodings, but if hit a stumbling block...

```
In [428]: badish[-3]
Out[428]: '\t\t\t"Kuzey r\xfczgari" (2007) {(#1.2)}  [Kaz\xc4\xb1m]\n'

In [429]: chardet.detect(badish[-3])
Out[429]: {'confidence': 0.98999999999999999, 'encoding': 'Big5'}

In [430]: unicode(badish[-3], 'Big5')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

~/src/imdb/<ipython console> in <module>()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'big5' codec can't decode bytes in position 11-12: illegal multibyte sequence
```

chardet reports a very high confidence in it's choice of encodings, but it doesn't decode...  Are there any other sensible approaches?

Comment: A little bit of hacking, specifically trying the detection on just the quoted portion, returns an encoding (it happens to be ISO-8859-2), with very low confidence, that actually does decode the whole line.  Im looking for a generalization though, that I can apply to the whole database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A point that can't be stressed too strongly: *You should not expect any reasonable encoding guess from a piece of text that is so short and has such a high percentage of plain old ASCII characters in it.*

About big5: chardet casts a very wide net when checking CJK encodings. There are lots of unused slots in big5, and chardet doesn't exclude them. That string is not valid big5, as you have found out. It is in fact valid (but meaningless) big5_hkscs (which used a lot of the holes in big5).

There are an enormous number of single-byte encodings that fit the string.

At this stage it's necessary to seek out-of-band help. Googling "Kuzey etc" drags up a Turkish TV series "Kuzey rüzgari" so we now have the language.

That means that if it was entered by a person familar with Turkish, it could be in cp1254, or iso_8859_3 (or _9), or mac_turkish. All of those produce gibberish for the [Kaz??m] word near the end. According to the imdb website, that's the name of a character, and it's the same gibberish as obtained by decoding with cp1254 and iso-8859-9 (KazÄ±m). Decoding with your suggested iso-8859-2 gives KazÄąm which doesn't look very plausible either.

Can you generalise this? I don't think so :-)

I would strongly suggest that in such a case that you decode it using latin1 (so that no bytes are mangled) and flag the record as having unknown encoding. You should use a minimum length cutoff as well.

**Update** For what it's worth, the_two_bytes_in_the_character_name.decode('**utf8**') produces U+0131 LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I which is used in Turkish and Azerbaijani. Further googling indicates that Kazım is a common-enough Turkish given name.

Comment: How very frustrating that the encoding varies at a rate faster than lines.  This data is in fact from IMDB...